# Dual-Ubuntu: how do I disable one OS from using the swap partition?

Tags: lubuntu, swap, lxde

I have both Ubuntu and Lubuntu installed on the same machine, on different partitions. They are both used for different things, and I like to hibernate my main Ubuntu installation to my single swap partition when I switch between them. However, they are both recognizing the same swap partition, and when I boot into Lubuntu after hibernating my Ubuntu installation, it tries to load from swap and all HELL breaks loose.

So I want to try to make Lubuntu stop recognizing the swap partition. This is a quad core machine, and Swap really isn't needed with LXDE.

Comment: You can turn off swap disk by typing this on terminal."sudo swapoff -a" if you ever won't to enable it just type "sudo swapon -a" only turn off your swap if you got ram memory more than 2GB (it's enough for everyday apps with web browsing)

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer(s) to your question when possible (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 1):

- Press `Alt+F2` and type: `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`; enter password when prompted
- Find a line like the following:

  ```
  # swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
  UUID=adc15cab-1cd4-4278-9a1d-59016cced6dd none      swap  sw    0       0
  ```
- Comment out the `UUID=` line by adding a `#` in front of it. Save and exit.
- Lubuntu will no longer attempt to use that swap partition.

Comment: sorry! my browser didn't load your answer in the first attempt. Is there any difference between this method and the simple "Sudo swapoff-a" method?

Comment: @Prasad: `swapoff` only disables swap, not remove its entry from `/etc/fstab`. In that case, an accidental `swapon`, or using other utilities such as gParted, etc. in particular ways may still enable the swap causing problems.

Comment: Thank you very much, never knew it before! thanks again!